# Getting NullPointerException while trying to get values from Shared Preferences because of context in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences, android-context

I have made a separate `asynctask` and I am storing some values to shared preferences in android but I am getting these values in all other activities. When I am trying to get this shared preferences values inside my `asynctask` it is giving me a `nullpointer` exception, I think it is because of context, but I don't know how to solve it.

**asynctask**

```
public class Updatelocation extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
    private Context mContext;

    public Updatelocation(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    String reg_no = Pref.getValue(mContext, Const.PREF_REG, "");
    String udid = Pref.getValue(mContext, Const.PREF_REG, "");

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        System.out
                .println(":::::::::::::::::::::::::::::Registration and udid:::::::::::::::::::::::"
                        + reg_no + "=========" + udid);
        String updateURL = Const.API_UPDATE_LOCATION + "?UDID=" + udid
                + "&latitude=" + arg0[0] + "&longitude=" + arg0[1]
                + "&registration_no=" + reg_no;

        updateURL = updateURL.replace(" ", "%");

        BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();
        System.out.println(":::::::::::::UPDATE URL:::::::::::;" + updateURL);
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(updateURL, BackendAPIService.POST);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        System.out.println("=============MY RESPONSE==========" + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog

    }
}
```

Comment: When dealing with a NPE is fundamental to look to the StackTrace. Post it so we can help.

Comment: And the exception occurs on which line...

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass your activity in doInBackgroud parameters and try this code:

```
Activity activity = (Activity) params[0];
Long newLong = Long.valueOf(0000);
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
Long lastDate = prefs.getLong(DATETIMEKEY, newLong);
```

For me it works ok.

I think the problem is passing the context in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your `NullPointerException` comes from these lines:

```
String reg_no = Pref.getValue(mContext, Const.PREF_REG, "");
String udid = Pref.getValue(mContext, Const.PREF_REG, "");
```

These two strings are defined as attributes of your `UpdateLocation` class. It means that they are instantiated **before** the constructor is called, and - at this moment - your `mContext` value is null. That is why you get a `NPE` when you try to get values from the preferences.

To fix it, you have to put these lines into your constructor:

```
private Context mContext;
String reg_no;
String udid;

public Updatelocation(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    reg_no = Pref.getValue(mContext, Const.PREF_REG, "");
    udid = Pref.getValue(mContext, Const.PREF_REG, "");
}
```